# Razor pages (cshtml) render HTML markup without the classic colors

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a web project in Visual Studio 2013 and I'm not able to see the classic colors for HTML tags (Maroon, Blue and Red). Instead all the HTML is black, except the Razor blocks, they show ok.
When I go to the Fonts options the colors are configured correctly but the editor seems to not consider the configuration values.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you try just plain HTML without any Razor? And let us know what you see? Also what version of Razor and Visual Studio 2013 are you using, and did you GAC anything yourself (like Razor or MVC)

Comment: I guess I didn't check for that. HTML only pages look also the same way. Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll let the editor team know. Can you share any more info/details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that the source code doesn't have syntax highlighting within the Visual Studio editor, outside of the Razor blocks?

It's possible that your default editor for cshtml files got switched to the wrong one somehow. Try right-clicking one of the cshtml files in question, doing an "Open With...", and choosing "HTML Editor".

If that doesn't work, try disabling any extensions you have installed that touch the HTML editor (e.g. Web Essentials, Productivity Power Tools, Indent Guides, etc).

If that doesn't work, I'd try resetting your settings from Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Reset all settings. You can back your settings up first, so you can restore them afterward if resetting them doesn't help.

Finally, if none of that works, I would try running a repair on Visual Studio from the installer. I've seen that fix strange issues like this before.

Comment: Any HTML Editor gives me the same result inside Visual Studio.

Comment: @ArturoMartinez: Updated my answer with a few other things to try.

Comment: Resetting the settings worked out. I think it was related to not have the theme extensions in all my machines.